# How to prevent specific QTreeView branches from being dragged?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` that represents a pair of lists as a tree data structure with two branches, and I would like to enable dragging elements between branches.  However, I would also like to disallow dragging the whole branch.
 Does anyone know if Qt offers any support for specifying which individual branch and node of a `QTreeView` can be dragged?

Comment: Did you notice that there is an answer?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Use [QStandardItem::setFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setFlags) to set `Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled` only on those items, you want to make draggable, e.g.:

```
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
```

For more information see [Qt::ItemFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum).

## Example

The following example creates two lists of items and allows the items to be dragged and dropped from list to list, but the lists themselves remain fixed, i.e. not draggable:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTreeView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *view = new QTreeView(this);
    auto *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    auto *list1 = createItem(tr("List 1"), true);
    auto *list2 = createItem(tr("List 2"), true);
    auto *rootItem = model->invisibleRootItem();

    rootItem->setFlags(rootItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled);

    list1->appendRow(createItem(tr("Item 1"), false));
    list1->appendRow(createItem(tr("Item 2"), false));
    list1->appendRow(createItem(tr("Item 3"), false));

    list2->appendRow(createItem(tr("Item 4"), false));
    list2->appendRow(createItem(tr("Item 5"), false));

    model->appendRow(list1);
    model->appendRow(list2);

    view->setModel(model);
    view->setDragEnabled(true);
    view->setAcceptDrops(true);
    view->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
    view->expandAll();
    view->setRootIsDecorated(true);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(300, 400);
}

QStandardItem *MainWindow::createItem(const QString &name, bool topLevel)
{
    auto *item = new QStandardItem(name);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

    if (topLevel)
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
    else
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;

    item->setFlags(flags);

    return item;
}
```

Comment: @RAM, did you try this solution?